# Does handles from WinHTTP Async, needs to be closed?

Tags: c++, windows, winhttp

Do you need to close the handles from [WinHttpOpen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpopen), [WinHttpConnect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpconnect) and [WinHttpOpenRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpopenrequest), after you use them **with** async mode WinHttpOpen().

I suppose they need to be, but **how is that done** because everything is asynchronously done, I've seen that the last called event from the callback was [WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_DATA_AVAILABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nc-winhttp-winhttp_status_callback#winhttp_callback_status_data_available), but im not sure if this is always the case (called last).

So do I need to close the handles, and if yes how?

Comment: Is [the information in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpclosehandle) not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WinHTTP handles need to be closed. [WinHttOpen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpopen) documentation:

> After the calling application has finished using the HINTERNET handle
>   returned by WinHttpOpen, it must be closed using the
>   [WinHttpCloseHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpclosehandle) function.

For asynchronous mode this can be done on the class destructor. In this case the handle can be a member variable so it's not lost. If you are using the main function, simply close the handle at the end.

Comment: Actually I figured it out after i posted the question :D. I did it when i get the final data response from the callback i set a flag and that flag is checked, then returns the function which had WinHttpOpen() and there it closes the handles